# Why are my Amazon S3 key permissions not sticking?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, acl, boto

I'm using the Python library `boto` to connect to Amazon S3 and create buckets and keys for a static website.  My keys and values are dynamically generated, hence why I am doing this programmatically and not through the web interface (it works using the web interface).  My code currently looks like this:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.create_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
bucket.configure_website('index.html', 'error.html')
bucket.set_acl('public-read')

for template in ['index.html', 'contact-us.html', 'cart.html', 'checkout.html']:
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = key
    k.set_acl('public-read')
    k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    k.set_contents_from_string(get_page_contents(template))
```

I'm getting various errors and problems with this code.  When the keys already existed and I used this code to update them, I would set the ACL of each key to `public-read`, but I'd still get 403 forbidden errors when viewing the file in a browser.

I tried removing all the keys to recreate them from scratch, and now I get a `NoSuchKey` exception.  Obviously the key isn't there because I'm trying to create it.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there a different way of doing this to create the keys as opposed to updating them?  And am I experiencing some kind of race condition when the permissions don't stick?

Comment: Have you tried these examples http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html in python shell??

Comment: I'm not sure, but should `bucket.get_key` be used when you work with already existing key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure why the code above didn't work, but I found a different (or newer?) syntax for creating keys.  The order of operations also appears to have some effect.  This is what I came up with that worked:

```
conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.create_bucket(store.domain_name)
bucket.set_acl('public-read')
bucket.configure_website('index.html', 'error.html')

for template in ['index.html', 'contact-us.html', 'cart.html', 'checkout.html']:
    k = bucket.new_key(template)
    k.set_metadata('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    k.set_contents_from_string(get_page_contents(template))
    k.set_acl('public-read') #doing this last seems to be important for some reason
```

Comment: just a tiny note: don't know about old boto versions but in new versions the "set_metadata()" part won't work because it is only set on creation. so the content-type in the example will be default, which is "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 4):

This has bitten me as well. boto's `set_contents_from_string()` method apparently sets the key's ACL to private, overriding any existing ACL.

So if you do `set_acl('public-read')`, followed by a `set_contents_from_string()`, the `'public-read'` will be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set the ACL in one go via the policy keyword arg:

```
k.set_contents_from_stream(buff, policy='public-read')
```